# Protecting my JavaScript File/Scripts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, obfuscation

So I know JavaScript **EDIT** *can be used as a* client side scripting language, which means it remains/runs on client side for certain actions. Unless you're using Node.js (which I am)

I am working on an app, I am using the MEAN Stack to most of my code is JavaScript based. I built my own API which is on the server of course.

While testing my app I saw that my JavaScript file/scripts were visible on the front end via inspect element.

[image]

**You can see in the above image that with inspect element you can see my scripts and angularJS services/factories/controllers. You can see my code making calls To my API. I could be passing sensitive data here, like credentials or anything else.**

Now before you all start screaming at me, I have done my research and I have found out that you CAN'T 100% secure or hide your client side scripts. The only thing that you can do is [obfuscation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation_(software)) making it harder for people to read & understand the code.

**My Question is that**, is it normal or a standard practice for people to be able to view HTTP requests to API/Servers as you can see in the attached image above? How can I make my code more secure.

Thanks.

Comment: If you remove http calls from the client side, how are you going to communicate with your api?

Comment: *"So I know JavaScript is a client side language, which means it remains/runs on client side for certain actions. Unless you're using Node.js (which I am)"* So...JavaScript is **not** a client-side language. It's a language. It's used client-side, server-side, in non-web apps, in PDFs, on the command line...

Comment: by the way, think about *HTTPS*

Comment: @MaciejKwas: HTTPS has no effect whatsoever on what the OP's asking about.

Comment: "*is it normal or a standard practice for people to be able to view HTTP requests to API/Servers*"
Now think for a while who can see those request? Only client browser?

Comment: @MaciejKwas OP wants to protect from users being able to see them from their browsers.

Comment: You should not send secrets (sensitive data) that you don't want anybody to know to the client.

Comment: @zerkms why credentials might be sensitive for user who passed them himself? It is sensitive for others... That's why passing credentials should go with UID over HTTPS to be most secured

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> My Question is that, is it normal or a standard practice for people to be able to view HTTP requests to API/Servers as you can see in the attached image above?

Yes, it's normal. No, there's nothing you can do to change that in a web application.

Answer (score 1):

> My Question is that, is it normal or a standard practice for people to be able to view HTTP requests to API/Servers as you can see in the attached image above? How can I make my code more secure.

Yes it is. Normally this doesn't matter as, for example, the person who can use their browser to enter a password is also the person who can then examine it. But you should still minimise the transfer of passwords: use temporary expiring tokens instead and tie them to a specific client.

You make your code more secure by securing the API. Regard the client as hostile. Even when you think you wrote the code, it may have been compromised.

So validate all calls a the server end, never trust anything sent by the client. If you need the client to store any sensitive data either encrypt it, or better store it at the server end and give the client a random nonce to match their request with their secret data.

Comment: Thank you. This really helped! I am currently using Session based authentication. And every actions sent to the API is first checked against the session. But I am thinking of making the change towards Token based authentication. But anyway thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Only the client side JS scripts will be visible, there is nothing the client can do to access or view the server side scripts.

Comment: …except the server accidentally leaks its own source. Known to have happened.

Answer (score 0):

Your front-end part is just a representation of data from backend. I think you if you keep/send/receive sensitive information it means that something went wrong. Of course there are cases when you have to pass sensitive data like credentials for authentication etc.. Think about redesigning your API in order to not leak sensitive data.